# iCloud php imap is not connecting

Tags: php, email, imap, icloud

I'm trying to access my icloud mailbox from my website. The code I'm using works fine with gmail, but when I try to connect to my iCloud account i get this error:

> Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.mail.me.com:993/ssl/imap} in /hp/bd/ab/lq/www/rechner/Messages/MailAusgabe.php on line 6

and this is my code:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.me.com:993/ssl/imap}", "myemail@me.com", "mypassword");
```

and this aswell:

> ```
> $mbox = imap_open("{imap.mail.me.com:993/ssl/imap}INBOX", "myemail@me.com", "mypassword");
> ```

I've already changed my password and tried some other accounts, but without success.

Comment: Your host likely firewalls this port. Please use a shell to verify you can even connect to the server, eg using openssl, socat, or even telnet.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I guess I'm just t stupid to understand what u mean. Could be so kind and explain it to me a little bit more detailed?

Comment: You need to, outside of your code, make sure you actually have access to connect to remote servers.  If it's a unix-like system and you have a shell account, a good way to do this is to login and try a command like `openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.me.com:993`.  If it's unable to connect, your web service will be unable to connect either.  It's not uncommon for this port to be firewalled.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this: *"{imap.mail.me.com:993/ssl/imap}"* by this: ***{imap.mail.me.com:993/imap/ssl}***